# TypeError: props.date.getTime is not a function. (In 'props.date.getTime()', 'props.date.getTime' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-datetimepicker

I'm using [react-native-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-date-picker) to show the date picker. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
...
    const [userUserDOB, setUserDOB] = useState(new Date());
...
                        <DatePicker
                            style={styles.dobPicker}
                            date={userUserDOB}
                            onDateChange={setUserDOB}
                            mode={'date'}
                            textColor={colors.darkBlue}
                        />
...

    dobPicker: {
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
```

This should show date picker but instead as soon as the screen loads I get this error:

> TypeError: props.date.getTime is not a function. (In 'props.date.getTime()', 'props.date.getTime' is undefined)

[image]

Comment: are you sure date has a compatible type with getTime?

Comment: @Alec you mean here `mode={'date'}`? I'm not doing anything with time, only want to show the date.

Comment: Sounds like DatePicker's onDateChange handler doesn't pass an actual date object to the callback (setUserDOB) but maybe a date string, like `"2021-07-13T08:00:00.000Z"`.

Comment: @Lennholm is there a way to check this? Because as soon as the `TextInput` comes `onFocus` I have a state `const [showDate, setDateShow] = useState(false);`  which I'm changing `<TextInput placeholder={"Select Birth Date"} value={userUserDOB} onFocus={() => { setDateShow(true) }} />`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, check this and let me know

```js
setDOB = (event, d) => {
        let a= d..getTime()
        console.log(a);
        this.setState({DOB:a})
    }
    
< DateTimePicker
    testID="dateTimePicker"
    value={new Date(2015, 0, 1)}
    mode="date"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    customStyles={{
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    maximumDate= {new Date(2015, 0, 1)}
    minimumDate={new Date(1950, 0, 1)}
    is24Hour={true}
    display="default"
    onChange={this.setDOB}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly check the date in prop and then pass it from `new Date()` as
`new Date( props.date ).getTime()` this will work for you i.a

Comment: Hi Umair, welcome to stack overflow. Can you please elaborate on what you mean? As I don't have a date prop, I just want to show today's date in case there is no date selected that is why I'm initializing the `userUserDOB` with a new date and not using the time.

Comment: const [date, setNewdate] = useState( new Date() )
....
const setDate = (data) => {
    setNewdate(data);
  }
....
 <View style={{ flex: 1 , justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
        <DatePicker
          date={date}
          onDateChange={setDate}
          mode={'date'}
        />
      </View>
.... this one is working for me

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```html
{!!userUserDOB?.getTime && <DatePicker
                            style={styles.dobPicker}
                            date={userUserDOB}
                            onDateChange={setUserDOB}
                            mode={'date'}
                            textColor={colors.darkBlue}
                        />}
```